# How to create a symmetric matrix from a numpy 1D array the most efficient way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a 1d `np.array`. Its length may vary according to user input, but it will always stay single-dimesional.
Please advise if there is an efficient way to create a symmetric 2d `np.array` from it? By 'symmetric' I mean that its elements will be according to the rule k[i, j] = k[j, i].

I realise it is possible to do with a python `for` loop and `list`s, but that is very inefficient.

Many thanks in advance!

**EXAMPLE:**
For example, we have `x = np.array([1, 2, 3])`. The desired result should be

```
M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [2, 1, 2],
              [3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: Give us a sample case?

Comment: efficiency hardly matters if the solution is not right.

Comment: @Mikhail T, based on your example posted, please see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Interpretation #1**

Seems like you are reusing elements at each row. So, with that sort of idea, an implementation using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) would be -

```
def symmetricize(arr1D):
    ID = np.arange(arr1D.size)
    return arr1D[np.abs(ID - ID[:,None])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [170]: arr1D
Out[170]: array([59, 21, 70, 10, 42])

In [171]: symmetricize(arr1D)
Out[171]: 
array([[59, 21, 70, 10, 42],
       [21, 59, 21, 70, 10],
       [70, 21, 59, 21, 70],
       [10, 70, 21, 59, 21],
       [42, 10, 70, 21, 59]])
```

---

**Interpretation #2**

Another interpretation I had when you would like to assign the elements from the input `1D` array into a symmetric `2D` array **without re-use**, such that we would fill in the upper triangular part once and then replicate those on the lower triangular region by keeping symmetry between the row and column indices. As such, it would only work for a specific size of it. So, as a pre-processing step, we need to perform that error-checking. After we are through the error-checking, we will initialize an output array and use row and column indices of a [`triangular array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) to assign values once as they are and once with swapped indices to assign values in the other triangular part, thus giving it the symmetry *effect*.

It seemed like [`Scipy's squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) should do be able to do this task, but from the docs, it doesn't look like it supports filling up the diagonal elements with the input array elements. So, let's give our solution a closely-related name.

Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
def squareform_diagfill(arr1D):
    n = int(np.sqrt(arr1D.size*2))
    if (n*(n+1))//2!=arr1D.size:
        print "Size of 1D array not suitable for creating a symmetric 2D array!"
        return None
    else:
        R,C = np.triu_indices(n)
        out = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=arr1D.dtype)
        out[R,C] = arr1D
        out[C,R] = arr1D
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [179]: arr1D = np.random.randint(0,9,(12))

In [180]: squareform_diagfill(arr1D)
Size of 1D array not suitable for creating a symmetric 2D array!

In [181]: arr1D = np.random.randint(0,9,(10))

In [182]: arr1D
Out[182]: array([0, 4, 3, 6, 4, 1, 8, 6, 0, 5])

In [183]: squareform_diagfill(arr1D)
Out[183]: 
array([[0, 4, 3, 6],
       [4, 4, 1, 8],
       [3, 1, 6, 0],
       [6, 8, 0, 5]])
```

Comment: interpretation #1 is what i wanted. Thank you. I should've added example the time i was initially asking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is a special Toeplitz matrix and easy to generate with scipy

```
from numpy import concatenate, zeros
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

toeplitz([1,2,3])

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

another special matrix interpretation can be using Hankel matrix, which will give you minimum dimension square matrix for a given array.

```
from scipy.linalg import hankel

a=[1,2,3]

t=int(len(a)/2)+1
s=t-2+len(a)%2

hankel(a[:t],a[s:])

array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

Comment: Yeah I had to update my solution based on OP's edits with the sample as I interpreted it wrongly before. So, with the go-to `toeplitz` taken, I had to revert to `broadcasting` and that's a bit slower than `toeplitz`, so I would have to say good choice! :)

Comment: karakfa, thank you! Tested both answers, they are both correct. Wish it was possible to accept both.

Comment: no problem. it's a learning experience and these might be useful for someone else too.